# Where can I add javax.media.jai Jar package in Java?

Tags: java, jar, classnotfoundexception

I am getting class not found(javax.media.jai.JAI) exception while running my code. I have downloaded(https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-client-downloads.html#jai-1_1_2_01-oth-JPR) the JAI jar and added in Project lib folder but not working getting same error again. where can I add this jar. Please advise.

Note : The is old servlet project structure there is no Maven features.

Error Log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.JAI
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

Comment: It seems like all the jai JAR files has been delete, even from the Maven repositories which I thought exist to prevent such a situation :(  At the moment the workaround is replacing it by a different JAI library. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23304/java-open-source-imaging-library-as-a-substitute-to-the-jai

Comment: @Robert - I have tried as you suggested alternate libraries, but its not working for me. Some functionality not working. Please let me know - where can I paste the updated JAI jar location(JDK lib or JRE lib or any specific location). Please help me.

Comment: I am sorry I also use JAI but it looks like JAI is finally dead.

Comment: Just in case somebody still wants the JAI 1.1.3 JAR file and searches for an off-site. The original version which was once published in the Maven repos had the SHA-1 `B179D2EFB1174658483E8B41BF4AC9D2EB5DE438` / SHA-256 `8B696CF067533545F44C2F68339E24AB1A2669153ED2081AA5BE8749F4D592BF` Especially using the SHA-1 value you are still able to find downloadable JAR files e.g. via Google.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoWZW.png)

You can go to build path and add ur external jars by downloading it online.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).